# Detect if other end of WebSocket unexpectedly disconnects

Tags: .net, websocket

I'm migrating from a `TcpClient` solution over to a `WebSocket` one. I have the following code to detect if the other end of the network connection has unexpectedly disappeared.

```cs
public bool GetIsAlive()
{
    if (TcpClient.Client is null) return false;
    if (IsDisposed) return false;
    try
    {
        TcpClient.Client.Blocking = false;
        bool hasDisconnected = TcpClient.Client.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead) && TcpClient.Client.Available == 0;
        return !hasDisconnected;
    }
    catch (SocketException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

https://peterlesliemorris.com/detect-if-the-other-end-of-a-tcpclient-has-disconnected/

How is this done for a `WebSocket`?

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is to try to send 0 bytes and then check the status of the `WebSocket`.

```cs
public async Task<bool> GetIsAliveAsync()
{
    if (IsDisposed) return false;
    if (Client.State != WebSocketState.Open) return false;
    if (Client.CloseStatus is not null) return false;

    byte[] buffer = Array.Empty<byte>();
    try
    {
        await Client.SendAsync(buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, endOfMessage: false, CancellationToken.None);
        bool isAlive = (Client.State == WebSocketState.Open && Client.CloseStatus is null);
        return isAlive;
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    catch (SocketException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

https://peterlesliemorris.com/detect-if-the-other-end-of-a-websocket-has-disconnected/